# Prove $p$$_n$$_+$$_1$ $<$ $2p_n$ without using the Bertrand's Postulate

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, alternative-proof

Recently I have been researching on the Bertrand's Postulate to find and elementary proof of it. I have been able to prove that (if I have not made a very pathetic mistake) for any composite $n$ $(\geq5)$, there exists at least one prime between $n$ and $2n$ (and that proof isn't similar to any of the earlier 'standard' proofs). Not only that, in each case I have found the prime which should be within the bound. But I am a bit skeptic about my proof, so I will post it later. However, where I am stuck at is regarding the proof of $p$$_n$$_+$$_1$ $<$ $2p_n$. Any suggestion as to prove this inequality (using elementary methods) without making use of the Bertrand's Postulate?

Comment: This inequality is equivalent to the Bertrand Postulate, so it is pretty hard to prove it without it.

Comment: I know that. As for an alternative suggestion if it can be proved that $c_n-n-1$ $>$ $\pi(n)$, then also my work will be done. Here $c_n$ denotes the $n$-th composite and $\pi(n)$ the prime counting function.

Comment: That is, if you prove this, you will have also proved Bertrand's postulate.

Comment: I suggest you at least post an outline of your proof

Comment: There is no "not a real question" reason to close anymore. It would have fit perfectly here.

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen: Fine then. Let me outline the proof. Let $n$ be an composite number . Then it is easy to prove that $2n$ $\geq$ $c_n$ $>$ $n$. Now note that $\pi(x)$ $\geq$ $\pi(y)$ $\iff$ $x\geq y$. Then we get $\pi(2n)$ $\geq$ $\pi(c_n)$ $\geq$ $\pi(n)$. But we see that equality in both side is impossible by our hypothesis and hence we get $\pi(2n)$ $>$ $\pi(c_n)$ $>$ $\pi(n)$. And this implies that $\pi(c_n)$-th prime is in between $2n$ and $n$ for any $n>5$.

Comment: (Your equivalence is false. $\pi(x)\ge\pi(y)$ and $y>x$ is possible.)

Comment: @AndresCaicedo: Can you give an example? Or can you give a proof?

Comment: But that is not the crux of the fallacy here: $x\ge y$ does imply $\pi(x)\ge \pi(y)$. How did you proved that equality is impossible at both sides?

Comment: @N.S. Why not posting your comment as an answer? (With at least slightly more detailed explanation why the two claims are equivalent. And that this means that by proving this, we automatically get a proof of Bertrand.) My opinion is that something like that can be considered answer to this question.

Comment: As Andre Caicedo says, your last premise is false: $x=3,y=4$

Comment: @chubakueno: What do you mean? $\pi(4)$ $=$ $\pi(3)$ $=$ $2$. How can my last premise be false? Can you be more elaborate?

Comment: You say that $\pi(x)\ge\pi(y)\implies x\ge y$. But  $\pi(3)\ge\pi(4), 3\not\ge 4$

Comment: @chubakueno: Yes you are right. The implication doesn't hold in general. But what about the inequalities $\pi(x)$ $\geq$ $\pi(p)$ $\implies$ $x$ $\geq$ $p$ and $\pi(x)$ $\leq$ $\pi(p)$ $\implies$ $x$ $\leq$ $p$, where $p$ is a prime.

Answer (score 2):

The inequality is equivalent to the Bertrand Postulate, so it is pretty hard to prove it without it.

Here is why:

**BP implies the inequality:**

Indeed, by BP, there exists a a prime number between $p_n$ and $2p_n$. This shows that

$$p_{n+1} < 2 p_n $$

**The inequality implies BP**

Let $n$ be any positive number, and let $p_{k}$ be the largest prime which is less or equal than $n$. Then, by the inequality $p_{k+1}<2 p_k$, we have

$$p_{k} \leq n < p_{k+1} < 2p_{k} \leq 2n$$

Therefore there exists a prime ($p_{k+1}$) strictly between $n$ and $2n$.

Comment: Why does this answer show that the inequality is hard to prove without Betrand's postulate ?

Comment: @Peter Because any proof of the inequality proves the BP... Note that the OP hopes to find a simpler proof of this which he wants to use to find a new simple proof of BP... The point I am trying to make is that this is not a simpler problem that the BP, so cannot be a shortcut towards a simpler proof: any simpler proof by this method yields the same simpler proof as a direct proof of BP...